# Using qsort with a define struct

Tags: c, algorithm, struct, qsort

I'm learning C and I'm solving [this challenge](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&page=show_problem&problem=2353), I'm not planning to submit it to the uva platform and the reason I'm coding this exercise is for leaning, maybe is not the best approach to the problem but I'm trying.

The input I print in my terminal is the following:

```
4
3
20 30 40 50 30 40
Res: 2
4 
20 30 10 10 30 20 40 50
Res: 4
3
10 30 20 20 30 10
Res: 2
4
10 10 20 30 40 50 39 51
Res: 3
```

The answers from each input test are incorrect and I believe the reason is the qsort function. I'm confuse about how to use the qsort function using a structure, I'm calling my structure that is called array, followed by the size of my input, then using sizeof(int) but do I need to use int or sizeof my structure, lastly I'm calling my compare function. My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Dolls{
  int w;
  int h;
}array[20005];

int cmp(struct Dolls a, struct Dolls b){
  if(a.w==b.w){
    return a.h < b.h;
  }else{
    return a.w > b.w;
  }
}

int arr[20005];
int dp[20005];
int n;

int bSearch(int num, int k){
  int low=1;
  int high = k;
  int mid;
  while(low<= high){
    mid = (low+high)/2;
    if(num>=dp[mid]){
      low=mid+1;
    }else{
      high=mid-1;
    }
  }
  return low;
}

int res_dolls(){
  int k=1;
  int i,pos;
  dp[i]=arr[1];
  for(i=2;i<=n;i++){
    if(arr[i]>=dp[k]){
      dp[++k] = arr[i];
    }else{
      pos = bSearch(arr[i],k);
      dp[pos] = arr[i];
    }
  }
  return k;
}

int main(){
  int t,j;
  scanf("%d",&t);
  while(t--){
    memset(array,0,sizeof(array));
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(j=1;j<=n;j++){
      scanf("%d %d",&array[j].w, &array[j].h);
    }
    qsort(array,n,sizeof(int),cmp);
    for(j=1;j<=n;j++){
      arr[j] = array[j].h;
    }
    printf("%d\n",res_dolls());
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to `#include <stdlib.h>` which won't help. Please maximise the compiler warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `cmp` function needs to be defined as `int (*)(const void *, const void *)` for it to work for `qsort`.

The way you're performing the comparisons is also not correct.  From the man page for qsort:

> The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, 
>   or greater  than  zero  if  the first argument is considered to be
>   respec- tively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.  If
>   two members compare as equal, their order in the sorted array is
>   undefined.

The comparisons you're doing return the result of the `<` or `>` operators, which is either 0 or 1.  You need to explicitly check each case and return the proper value.

```
int cmp(const void *va, const void *vb){
  const struct Dolls *a = va;
  const struct Dolls *b = vb;

  if(a->w > b->w) {
      return 1;
  } else if(a->w < b->w){
      return -1;
  } else if(a->h > b->h) {
      return 1;
  } else if(a->h < b->h){
      return -1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

As for the call to `qsort`, you need to give it the size of an array element, i.e. the whole struct, not the size of the subfield:

```
qsort(array,n,sizeof(struct Dolls),cmp);
```

EDIT:

Fixed the error with the parameter names.  Also changed how the sort is performed to conform to how the comparison function must behave.

Comment: I understand that I need to change it in order to accept any type of input but when I changed it I receive this warning: redefinition of 'a' with a different type: 'const struct Dolls *' vs 'const void *'

Comment: Oh I found the error the variable name a was used twice in a single scope. Changing const struct Dolls *va = a, fixed the mistake.

Comment: Much better compare!